# PayPal Standard not giving option for Check out as Guest

Tags: paypal

MVC 3 VB.NET applicaiton... Using express checkout with html razor view. I have tried everything mentioned in all of the docs i could google for as well as the ones on paypal's dev network. Our Paypal account is setup to allow users to Check out as Guest without requiring paypal account creation or login. However when users are taken to the paypal site after clicking the checkout button there is no option to check out as guest. I am including my checkout view for reference. Please understand that this is a valid question and do not down vote it. If there is something not clear I will clarify it..

```
 @modeltype xxxxxxx.orderVM
 @Code
 ViewData("Title") = "CheckOut"
 End Code


<p style="text-align:center">Once you complete your transaction you will be redirected       back to the site</p>
<p></p>
<p style="text-align:center">We will process your payment within 24 hours at which time you will recieve a confirmation email which you will need for addmission. Along with a PDF attachment in this email which is your parking permit.. Please print and follow the instructions</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p style="text-align: center"> Please Click on the paypal button below to be redirected to the PayPal Site to complete the payment Transaction</p>

<form id="PayPal" name="PayPal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
@Html.Hidden("cmd", "_cart")
@Html.Hidden("upload", "1")
@Html.Hidden("business", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("PayPalMerchantEmail"))
@Html.Hidden("page_style","primary")
@Html.Hidden("custom", Model.id.ToString)
@Html.Hidden("image_url", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/content/images/xxxxxxxxLogo.jpg")
@Html.Hidden("cpp_header_image",  "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/content/images/xxxxxxxLogo.jpg")
@Html.Hidden("cpp_logo_image", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxxe.com/content/images/xxxxxxxLogo.jpg")
@Html.Hidden("return", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com/")
@Html.Hidden("cancel_return", "http://www.xxxxxxxxxx.com")

@Html.Hidden("first_name", Model.first_name)
@Html.Hidden("last_name", Model.last_name)
@Html.Hidden("address1", Model.address1)
@Html.Hidden("address2", Model.address2)
@Html.Hidden("city", Model.city)
@Html.Hidden("state", Model.state)
@Html.Hidden("zip", Model.zip)



@If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Class1) Then

@Html.Hidden("item_name_1", Model.Class1)
@Html.Hidden("amount_1", Model.fee1)
@Html.Hidden("quantity_1", ViewBag.quan)
@Html.Hidden("shipping_1", " 0.00 ")
@Html.Hidden("handling_1", " 0.00 ")

End If
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_xpressCheckout.gif" align="middle" style="text-align:center"/>
</form>
```

I do not feel the code for the controller is required here since it does pass all the values correctly into the view... The only issue is I can not get check out as guest working...

Comment: Edited your question, as you're using Website Payments Standard, not Express Checkout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you turned on 'Account Optional' in your PayPal Profile?
Which country is your account located in? The guest checkout functionality is not available in all countries yet.

Comment: It should also be noted that for some reason the paypal check out page is still showing our email address at the top of it instead of our logo..

Comment: Is the email address confirmed? Does the email address 100% match the address of the PayPal account? If it doesn't recognize the email address, it won't let you check out as guest, exactly the issue you're seeing

Comment: Is there a way to send the secure merchant id to paypal instead of the business email address? I have looked everywhere for information on what variable to pass to paypal to use the merchant id but have found nothing...

Comment: Good to hear! :-) You can also send the secure merchant ID; it goes in the same `business` parameter.