# PayPal Payments Standard Guest checkout

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Im integrating an MVC4 website with Paypal and all has gone quite smoothly until now. However, when I click through, the buyer does not get the option to complete the purchase as a guest.
I'm using the Paypal HTML payments standard method and searched around and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529209/paypal-standard-not-giving-option-for-check-out-as-guest) page and [Paypal itself](https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/cps/general/OptionalAccount-outside) said to make sure
 'Account optional' was off in my profile. I'm in my sandbox profile now, but under 'website payment preferences' there is no such option. I just have:

- Auto return for website payments
- Payment data transfor
- Encrypted website payments
- Contact telephone no
- Express checkout settings (just for german payment methods!)

Does anyone know where this setting is now?
The person I'm building the site does not want users to have to have a paypal account, so guest checkout functionality is required.
Unfortunately the Paypal website doesn't really help - searches for guest checkout turn up little.

Any help really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me what country you're in?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, I guess it might be related to your location or your customers location (Outside the US).

I have called PayPal Support and after about an hour of discussion they said something like that.

I hope that this is not the right answer (I hope there is some sort of setting we can do to change that, and we are just missing it).

also check that link it might help:
[PayPal Standard not giving option for Check out as Guest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529209/paypal-standard-not-giving-option-for-check-out-as-guest)

Comment: Can you tell me what country you're in?

Comment: Both my merchant and test customers are set to UK locale

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the receiving account has **verified** status (eg, that you've linked it to a bank account).

Only verified accounts are eligible for guest checkout.
Another common pitfall is that you might have made a typo on the email address of the receiver.

Make sure it's the exact same one that's used to log into the PP account (or at least that it's associated, and confirmed to the account)

Comment: Thanks - i've double checked the email addresses and they do match. How do you verify an account on the sandbox?

Comment: IF it's in the sandbox, it's easier to create a new account from scratch. Make sure that when you create it, you add a bank account and a credit card.  This will make it verified.

You can create new accounts here:
https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_create-account-session

Answer (score 0):

This topic forum is the best place I've found for a checklist of requirements to receive guest payments on paypal: 
https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal-Archive/buy-now-button-requires-paypal-login-or-account/m-p/15587